# Need Advice on how to store data

Tags: sql

I am creating a application for stock management.
I have a table called Inventory.
It contains below sample values.

| Id | Item | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Chicken | 10 |
| 2 | Onion | 12 |

Now I want to create Assembled items. (Collection of Items).
E.g Chicken biriyani is a assembled item. For this i need to store required items and its count. (Chicken, onion, tomato,. etc)
Like wise i have to create around 100 assembled items.

I want some suggestion how to store the data in db. Whether I need to create 100 table for each assembled item or is there any other best approach to store assembled items.

Answer (score 1):

You want two tables, one for the entity "assembled item" and one for the items in them.

```
create table assemblies as (
    assemblyId int primary key,
    . . .
);

create table assemblyItems as (
     assemblyItemId int primary key,
     assemblyId int not null references assemblies (assemblyId),
     itemId int not null references inventory(itemId),
     quantity <number of some sort>
);
```

Note:  I think you need an `items` table which the `inventory` table should reference.  They can be combined into a single table; `items` would be a more appropriate name.